# Locating font files

Tags: bash, find, fonts, locate, fontconfig

There's a utility called `fc-list` in the `fontconfig` library, that's good for listing installed fonts.
It detected a *few hundred* system fonts.

---

I ended up using `find` to locate all files with common typeface file extensions, which worked reasonably well. It returned *several thousand* matches, including a few false positives, and probably missed some files with omitted extensions, or whatever. Point is, relying on a naming convention isn't ideal:

```
font_finder () 
{ 
    font_extensions=('mf' 'otc' 'otf' 'ttc' 'ttf');
    for x in "${font_extensions[@]}";
    do
        find / -type f -iname "*.$x";
    done 2> /dev/null
}
```

---

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Are you looking for any possible font file on your server, or where `fontconfig` is looking, or common directories, or...?

Comment: @StephenHarris @StephenHarris System wide. I really only mentioned `fontconfig` & `fc-list` to prevent people from suggesting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***file*** utility,
maybe in connection with *find*.

an output of *file* as example:

```
$ file Gelasio-Italic-0.2.ttf
Gelasio-Italic-0.2.ttf: TrueType Font data, digitally signed, 18 tables, 1st "DSIG", 30 names, Macintosh, Copyright (c) 2013-2018, Sorkin Type Co with Reserved Font Name 'Gelasio'GelasioItalic1.005;STC
```

Among the other information, it includes your *magic* keyword **Font**.

Comment: That's useful for true type and open type formats, but some others return more generic informations like `LaTeX auxiliary file`, `ASCII text`, `data`, etc.

Comment: could you share/post an example of those files?

Comment: Sure, what info do you want exactly? There's not much to show. It literally only says something like: `example.mf: data` without any additional info.

Comment: oh, I do not known about those files! But I have to add, they are real text files, interpreted by Tex. Unfortunately they do not have a common header as well, thus it's impossible at first glance decide if a .mf file is a text file mis-named or a font file...